# Sql script to correct data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I have the following data in a table:

```
Id      | InventoryId | RevisionId
-----------------------------------
1001    |   1234    |   1
1002    |   2235    |   1
1003    |   2235    |   2
1004    |   2235    |   2
1005    |   2235    |   3
1006    |   2235    |   4
1007    |   3234    |   1
1008    |   3234    |   2
1009    |   3234    |   3
1010    |   3234    |   3
1011    |   3234    |   4
1012    |   3234    |   5
1013    |   3234    |   5
1014    |   3234    |   6
```

I want to write a script which provide me data correction in following way

```
Id   |  InventoryId | RevisionId
---------------------------------
1001    |   1234    |   1
1002    |   2235    |   1
1003    |   2235    |   2
1004    |   2235    |   3
1005    |   2235    |   4
1006    |   2235    |   5
1007    |   3234    |   1
1008    |   3234    |   2
1009    |   3234    |   3
1010    |   3234    |   4
1011    |   3234    |   5
1012    |   3234    |   6
1013    |   3234    |   7
1014    |   3234    |   8
```

Can we do this with a SQL script?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

use `row_number()`

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by InventoryId order by id) as newRevisionId
from tablename
```

Comment: exact same answer I was about to post and saw this.

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran, you can still post it just add some explanation so that it becomes unique :)

Comment: I'm upvoting this on the grounds (perhaps not intended by the author) that the OP might not even want to do an update, but rather just generate this sequence when he needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE(Id INT,InventoryId INT,RevisionId INT)

    INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT 1001,1234,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1002,2235,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1003,2235,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1004,2235,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1005,2235,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1006,2235,4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1007,3234,1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1008,3234,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1009,3234,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1010,3234,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1011,3234,4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1012,3234,5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1013,3234,5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1014,3234,6

    ;WITH cte
    AS(
        SELECT Id,InventoryId,RevisionId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InventoryId ORDER BY id) AS NewRevision FROM @Table
      )
    UPDATE cte SET RevisionId=newRevision

    SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: can we update only those record in which revisionId is duplicate instead of updating all the revisionId

Comment: include "where RevisionId<>newRevision" as where clause in update statement

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the values back to the table with new RevisionId, you can use `CTE` like following.

```
;with cte as
(
 select *, row_number() over(partition by InventoryId order by id) as rn
 from @table 
)

 update cte set RevisionId = rn
```

Answer (score 0):

create table #temp1(A int,B int)

insert into #temp1(a,b)values
(1001,1234)
,(1002,2235)
,(1003,2235)
,(1004,2235)
,(1005,2235)
,(1006,2235)
,(1007,3234)
,(1008,3234)
,(1009,3234)
,(1010,3234)
,(1011,3234)
,(1012,3234)
,(1013,3234)
,(1014,3234)

select *,row_number() over(partition by b order by b asc) from #temp1